# PHP explode text to array

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to convert the contents of [this link](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html) (only the Country/code list) into an array.
To do so I tried using explode(), but exploding on \r, \n, \r\n, or \n\r doesn't work.

Anybody knows what they are using?
I only need the country name and the 2 letter-code.

Comment: the best way to grab the data in the page is using a simple dom parser. very easy to grab the table and it's contents

Comment: @DevZer0 It's not a HTML table. It's a text file inside `<pre>` tags. DOM parser won't help here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

consider using this page instead - http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_txt.htm

or in XML
http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_xml.htm

as it will be easier to parse!

To do it programmatically...

```
$country_arr = [];
$raw = file_get_contents("http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_txt.html");
$lines = explode("\n",$raw);
foreach ($lines as &$line) {
    $bits = explode(";",$line);
    $country_arr[$bits[0]] = $bits[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, exactly what I needed! I will thank you in exactly 9 minutes.

Comment: These are link only answers. You can read **[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)** as to why this is more a comment than an answer. You can also add code to help OP and flesh out your post with examples, but in it's current state, this isn't a good answer to the question and is more worthy of a comment.

Comment: @Patrick and that attitude is why your accepted answer as -3

Comment: That's much better :)

Answer (score 2):

Your work has already been done:

**[PHP Array of ISO 3166 Country Codes](http://www.signalfire.co.uk/blog/php-array-iso-3166-country-codes)**

Comment: I was assuming you wanted to keep your list up to date???? there are literally hundreds of ways you could have compiled a one off list, typed it, compiled it in excel, painted it using water colors... where's the fun in copying it from a blog!!!

Comment: This should be a comment. The question is about how to explode text into an array. Remember that Q&A must help future visitors

Comment: @Patrick something about reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What if another country gets discovered ey ey? your list will always be out of date until another thread is opened on stack overflow on how to update it

Comment: I don't see how parsing the codes from a text file instead of copying a ready-made array would somehow magically keep the array up to date.

Comment: Wow, I really don't know what i'm talking about haha

Comment: @HamZa this indeed should've been a comment, my bad.

Comment: @dodo geen probleem. You're new, until next time :)

Answer (score 1):

On website [www.iso.org](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes) you have [HTML](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements.htm), [Text](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_txt.htm) and [XML](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_xml.htm) versions.

Parsing **TXT** version :

```
$a = [];
$d = file_get_contents('http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_txt.htm');
foreach (explode("\r\n", trim($d)) as $i => $v) {
    if (!$i) continue;
    $v = explode(";", $v);
    $a[$v[1]] = $v[0];
}
print_r($a);
```

Parsing **XML** version :

```
$a = [];
$d = file_get_contents('http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements_xml.htm');
foreach (simplexml_load_string($d) as $v) {
    $a[ (string)$v->{'ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code_element'} ] = (string)$v->{'ISO_3166-1_Country_name'};
}
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this only once, copy the text in a notepad, search & replace any unnecessary characters, and then do the explode().

If you need to do it on demand, by code, then program the same search&replace actions by php.

Comment: Complicated situation, I couldn't use the notepad search/replace thing

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using PHP.

```
preg_match('/^([\w\s]+\w)\s+(\w{2})\s+\w{3}\s+\d{3}\s*$/', $contents, $matches);
```

You'll get an array with the needed information.